# Interprocess or adb communication with AndroidJUnit

Tags: android, unit-testing, adb, android-instrumentation

I want to know, does any way exist to communicate with system during instrumentation test execution.
For example: 
I have a phone with IR port on onboard & I can work with it through private SDK, also I can tune it with my application. In my Instrumentation test cases I want test app behavior based on external events which I want to configure before test separate test execution.
It's looks like

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    setupExternalCondition(condition1_ON); // setup external transiver
    assertNotNull(IR.read());
    assertTrue(assertIR.write());

    setupExternalCondition(condition1_OFF); 
    assertNotNull(IR.read());
    assertFalse(IR.write());
}
```

It's very simple example but there is a lot of "conditions", and sdk updating frequencies to high. I can't do all of this verification manually, and can't ask "transiver&SDK team" make a mock states list for writing just a unit test for coverage. So I want somehow inject external component execution to TestRuner for receiving events(or testName before test case execution) on local machine(or CI machine) to setup external condition.

Simple solution(I think) to run a tcp server on appUnderTest and request external condition change - I am not sure does it possible, and not sure about stable connection(wifi), so may be it's possible to do over adb.

Any suggestions?

P.S: test device has root permissions.

Answer (score 0):

So, find not bad but not ideal solution. 
Still wait for better proposition, if not may be this answer will be helpful for someone; 
For "building the bridge" between local machine and AndroidJUnitTest I add next class to tests:

```
class IPCServiceBridge extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String FILTER_ID = "IPC_SERVICE";
    private static IPCServiceBridge sInstance;
    private boolean mIsPermitted;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("ipc.service.action")) {
            mIsPermitted = true;
        }
    }


    public static IPCServiceBridge getInstance() {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new IPCServiceBridge();
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
            filter.addAction("ipc.service.action");
            Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext();
            context.registerReceiver(sInstance, filter);
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    public void sendIpcCommand(String commandName) {
        try {
            int i = 30;
            mIsPermitted = false;
            while (i > 0) {
                pub("request:" + commandName);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                if (mIsPermitted) {
                    break;
                }
                i--;
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        if (!mIsPermitted) {
            throw new RuntimeException("IPC service does not respond");
        }
    }

    private static void pub(String msg) {
        Log.e(FILTER_ID, msg);
    }
}
```

Than I start adb logcat -s "filter_name", parse and check which condition should be applied  for InsttUnit test. When conditions is ready i send back broadcast receiver with required action.

```
@Test
public void test2() throws Exception {
    IPCServiceBridge.getInstance().sendIpcCommand("CONDITION#123");
}
```

Work good, but I'm not sure that it will be super stable.